# Reading from a keyboard using python-hidapi on OS X

Tags: python, macos, hid

I'm writing a python script to access keyboard input regardless of the frontmost window (I swear this isn't a key logger!). I'm using OS X so using libusb/pyusb won't work because OS X won't let you claim HID devices. I thought that [HIDAPI](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) might be the solution, so I've installed [cython-hidapi](https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi) but I don't seem to be able to read from the keyboard. Here's my code:

```
import hid
import time

vendor_id = 1452 #apple
product_id = 523 #older apple keyboard

h = hid.device()
h.open(vendor_id, product_id)
h.set_nonblocking(1)

start = time.time()
keys = []
i = 0
while (time.time()-start)<10:
    #I press keys quickly during this 10s
    i = i + 1
    try:
        d = h.read(i)
        if d:
            keys.append([i,d])
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(.01)

h.close()
print d #prints empty list
print i #gets to a reasonably large value (>800)
```

I'm looping over various values for the read size because I wasn't sure what value I need to put there, but no matter what the value is there I don't seem to get any result from `read()`. Help?

Comment: did you try as root? sudo your script.